React native Expo build error in firebase service
I am having a problem that I am not being able to solve, when running eas build android I am having a Gradle error which I go to the expo console to see the error and I have the following one.
Error gradle building
This happened after updating the version of sdk expo 49 to 50. I updated the necessary dependecies. Executing expo-doctor don't have issues
Version SDK Expo 50.
Node: 21.21.0
I tried:
Use expo prebuild and modify AndroidManifest in the line suggest but this didn't work.

The end of the build log is rarely useful.  Start from the top of the log and scan down until you find the very first ERROR listed.  That is the thing you want to look into.  The build runs a number of processes in parallel.  Typically the error at the end of the build log simply lets you know that "something went wrong".

@GregFenton It is the first error that appears in the logs, so the problem is that line.
Update: I tried again to do expo prebuild and I have found that the line is repeated 2 times, how can I generate an eas build after expo prebuild has generated the android and ios folder?

Why do a prebuild?  Why not remain in Continuous Native Generation (formerly known as "Managed Workflow") ?  I cannot see a valid reason that an app developer would use prebuild prior to submitting to EAS Build.  Let EAS do the prebuild with each and every build.

@GregFenton. i don't find another solution, the el problem is caused for line
"
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:15:88-137 Error:
Attribute meta-data#com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color@resource value=(@color/notification_icon_color) from AndroidManifest.xml:15:88-137
is also present at [:react-native-firebase_messaging] AndroidManifest.xml:40:13-44 value=(@color/white).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml to override."

I read the error message the first time.  Since it is an issue with the manifest file, I recommended that you get out of a "bare workflow" and return to the CNG approach for building your custom client app.  If you still have that issue, then there's something to look into.  But because you did a prebuild you are now in "Bare Workflow" and anything that gets messed up in the native projects (android, ios) is your problem.  Under CNG, it would be Expo's problem.
